# How to pipe input from a Java program to another using Bourne Shell

Tags: java, shell, pipe

I have two simple Java programs and I want to pipe the result of the "Test" to the "Test2".

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello from Test");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Test2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.printf("Program Test piped me \"%s\"",args[0]);
    }
}
```

After I compiled both of .java files I tried to run the pipe command from terminal

**`java Test | java Test2`**, but I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which means that the args array is not initialized?

How can the Test2 application take the outputstream value that Test.main() produced through piping?

Comment: Using `>` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use xargs:

```
java Test| xargs -I ARGS java Test2 ARGS
```

Answer (score 4):

Pipes connect one program’s standard output to another program’s standard input, not to the other program’s command-line arguments.

The second class will not get the piped output as arguments to its `main` method; it will get the piped output as its standard input.  So you want to read the information from `System.in`:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws IOException {
        BufferedReader stdin =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        stdin.lines().forEachOrdered(
            line -> String.format("Program Test piped me \"%s\"", line));
    }
}
```